# Firefox search history via wild cards

Tags: firefox, history

In Firefox I can type part of an URL and Firefox provides a list from browse history.

Now I'd like to use wildcards. Is it possible and if yes how?

Example:
Let's say I search for theme firefox on superuser.com
then I would type `superuser.com*firefox` to retrieve all URLs from superuser.com with theme firefox.(Since the Topic of the question is part of the URL)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about vanilla Firefox, but Norwell add-on is capable of doing this. I've tested it and it worked fine.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/norwell/